# Build multiple linear regression model in R?

Tags: regression, linear-regression, prediction, predict, hypothesis-test

I am trying to construct a `multiple linear regression model` that i am going to use for future `prediction`.
In My code, i constructed the model using `DF` data where `Y` is my response variable while `X1` and `X2` independent variables. After fitting the model, i want to use the model (ie coefficients) to `predict` the year 2017 response variable (ie., `Y`). I would then want to plot the predicted value for the 2017 against the actual value of `Y` (ie `DF$Actual`) to see my model performance.

```
library(lubridate)

set.seed(1500)
DF <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2000-01-01"), to = as.Date("2010-12-31"), by = "days"), 
                         Y = runif(4018, 0,50), X1 = runif(4018, 2,45), X2 = runif(4018, 12, 55))

DF1 <- data.frame(Date = seq(as.Date("2017-01-01"), to = as.Date("2017-09-30"), by = "days"), 
                  Actual = runif(273, 0,50), X1 = runif(273, 2,45), X2 = runif(273, 12, 55))
ML_Model <- lm(data = DF, Y~X1+X2)
#summary(ML_Model)

Pred_Model <- predict(ML_Model, data.frame(X1 = DF1$X1, X2 = DF1$X2))

# plot the prected Y vs Acutal Y from DF1.......
```

Comment: what is your issue exactly?

Comment: I am not able to use the `Pred_Model` to forecast `(Y)` using data from `DF1`

Comment: do you get error?looks fine for me and working perfectly to me

Comment: My bad. i was exploring a different variable instead `Pred_Model`. I am tired and i do need a break :).

Comment: maybe `plot(DF1$Actual, predict(ML_Model, DF1))`?